# Arithmetic progression , find $n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions

Given arithmetic progresion $20,17,14,\ldots$

Find smallest value of $n$ so $y_n<0$.

I can find value of $n$ by mind , but do not know how to write the solution.

Comment: `Reduce[FindSequenceFunction[{20, 17, 14, 11}, n] < 0, Integers]` but I suppose it is a math homework, not a Wolfram Mathematica question, right?

Comment: @Kuba , oh yes. Sorry wrong category

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming $y_0=20$, your arithmetic progression has closed form

$$y_n=20-3n$$

Now let us solve the following inequality.

$$0>20-3n$$
$$3n>20$$
$$n>\frac{20}{3}=7-\frac{1}{3}$$

The minimum integer value of $n$ that satisfies the condition is
$n=7$.

Comment: Thank you , this is what I was looking for!